# Vim colorscheme changes with terminal theme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

So this seems a bit odd to me, but I have a theme I made for vim, and when I change my terminal's colors, it changes the color in vim as well.

[image]

Here is the vim colorscheme with the matching terminal color scheme applied.

If I change the terminal color scheme to a light one, if changes my vim color scheme to this.

[image]

Here is my repo 
https://github.com/mhartington/oceanic-next

Any idea whats up? This doesn't seem to happen in any other theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I have to admit that I'm not very knowledgeable about this, so am very likely to be wrong, but in case this is not answered-

I believe terminal colorschemes map color-names to specific ansi codes. Vim themes can take colors in hex-codes or in numeric codes where number is from 0 to (number of colors supported by terminal - 1 ). Each of these colors would map to the color-names that the terminal has assigned, which in turn would map to ANSI codes. A terminal assignment of a color-code would depend on its theme. Its likely that your other themes give colors in hex codes.

Try running: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349 with different terminal themes maybe and see?

Comment: You may have better luck with a 256-color capable terminal type like `xterm-256color`, which does not rely on the 16 or so default color codes that each terminal theme chooses how to map to actual color.

Comment: Well thats the thing, this is in iterm, which does have 256 color support, so that's what I was confused